# SQL: Is there a way to sort a list of rows in a table numerically without adding a new column?

Tags: sql, rows

I want to order a list of rows in a table numerically without adding a new column to the table so that the column isn't altered. The new list I want to order numerically is based on some constraints I set on the data I selected.

Ex:

Number     Title      Year

```
1        Movie      2016
2        Movie      1983
3        Movie      2000
```

and so on.

I've tried using ORDER BY, but in order to do so there needs to be a new column to order it by. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Edit #1: In case it's unclear, I want to add in the number 1, 2, 3 and so on (a number increasing numerically for each movie) without adding a new column to the table.

Edit #2: I'm using Toad as my database. Sorry for the lack of clarity, this is one of my first questions. Thanks!

Comment: which db you are using ??

Comment: Are you trying to sort by the column with the contents Movie #32? Are there other column attributes you would like to sort by?

Comment: What are the columns you currently have? It's not clear from the example.

Comment: What is the table schema and on which property do you wanna sort?

Comment: update your question and show your code  too

Comment: You didn't specify the database you are using. For example with MS Sql Server you can use Row_Number().

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with TOAD, and I see you don't want to add a column, but is a calculated field an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I just need to use COUNT(). Thanks for your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

In sqlserver you could use

```
 select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER() , title, year  
 from my_table
```

in mysql you could add  row num this way

```
set @row = 0;
select @row := @row+1, title, year  
from your_table
```

In Oracle you can use rownum

```
select rownum, title, year  
from your_table
```

Comment: would this ever work? and how do you know it is MS Sql Server?

Comment: To be fair the op wasn't specific and the answer was, not sure why the downvote

Answer (score -1):

If the issue is that you do not want to add this column to the existing table have you considered importing the data into a temporary table and assigning some kind of index?

```
    //Add this to drop the table in case it already exists
    IF(OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TEMP_TABLE') IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN 
           DROP TABLE #TEMP_TABLE
    END

    DECLARE @NUMBER INT = 0
    SELECT TITLE, YEAR, @NUMBER AS [KEY] INTO #TEMP_TABLE FROM YOUR_TABLE

    UPDATE #TEMP_TABLE 
    SET @NUMBER = @NUMBER + 1,
    [KEY] = [KEY] + @NUMBER

    SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TABLE
```

Comment: Pretty sure that will set them all to 1

Comment: Yeah I fixed my mistake. I had someone talking to me while I was trying to type.